# pg_hba.conf lines 127.0.0.1 and ::1/128?

Tags: postgresql

What is the meaning of these 2 lines in my pg_hba.conf?
I am guessing the first is to allow local connections, but what about the 2nd?

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Answer (score 4):

Both trust local connections.

`127.0.0.1/32` is the typical IPv4 localhost address (although the [entire `127.0.0.0/8`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330#section-2) is reserved for loopback).

`::1/128` is the IPv6 address for loopback; cf [section 2.4 of RFC4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.4).